# Join foreach laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i have this

```
public function deals(){

    $matchThese = [ 'suspended' => 0, 'status' => 1, 'approved' => 1 ];

    $deals = ListsDeals::where( $matchThese )->orderBy( 'start_date' )->get();

    $list = DB::table( 'lists' )
        ->join( 'list_has_deals', 'lists.id', '=', 'list_has_deals.list_id' )
        ->where( 'list_has_deals.deal_id', '=',  12)
        ->select( 'lists.id' )
        ->get();

    $categories = DB::table( 'lists_categories' )
        ->join( 'list_has_categories', 'lists_categories.id', '=', 'list_has_categories.category_id' )
        ->where( 'list_has_categories.list_id', '=', $list[0]->id )
        ->select( 'lists_categories.title' )
        ->get();

    return view( "deals" )
            ->with( "deals", $deals )
            ->with( "categories", $categories );

}
```

I want to obtain the value of title for the categories in lists, but first i need to obtain the deals for the lists in less words

I have

```
Deals - Lists - lists_has_deals

Categories - Lists - lists_has_deals
```

Both are belongsToMany, i want obtain in the deals the categories belonging to the list that is associated with the offer.

In my example that works fine but the 12 need to be a foreach of the $deals not be number static, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a has many through or intermediate pivot table on lists_has_deals. If I'm understanding your question, lists should have the necessary reference to both deals and categories.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many
specifically withPivot()